# Spring JSTL/EL form:select options from comma delimited string

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I'm using Spring 3.0.5.

I've got a comma delimited string "A, B, C, D".  Is it possible to build the list of options for a form:select input from this string?

I'm looking for something like:

```
<form:select path="foo.value" cssClass="formInput">
   <form:options items="${myCommaString}"/>
</form:select>
```

or do I need to do a for each loop?

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I don't know what type of value it accepts, but if it accepts a `String[]`, then you can use `fn:split()`.

Comment: damn balus you're a genius <form:options items="${fn:split(myCommaString, ', ')}"/>...post your answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSTL [`fn:split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) to split a string on a delimiter into an array of substrings.

```html
<form:options items="${fn:split(myCommaString, ', ')}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

BalusC is right - [`<form:options>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options) accepts a collection, map or array of objects. So use `fn:split(..)` But in your case I'm not sure it will work. A select option needs two strings - a value (sent to the server on submission) and a display value (shown to users). Perhaps it will assume the same for both, so try it. If it doesn't work, you'll need the `itemValue` and `itemLabel` parameters.

Comment: yes this was one of my thoughts as well...but it works perfectly.  Just waiting for balus to post an answer so I can give him credit.  Appreciate the help!